# Visual studio lost connection to Repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

I did see some things going around about this but answers point to update of visual studio 2017 or 2019. I just updated my VS 2022 issue persists.

I have been coding for a solid 2 months within my master branch. I just went to check in the changes, and I notice it said Select Repository usually where the branches are. In my git options window, I don't have a branch. When I select my repository, nothing happens, as if I am already in that repository.

I am utilizing my company's .visualstudio.com which does use Git but it used to be Microsoft's team foundation service, then they switched to git. Generally, people offer to run some git commands... I am not familiar with that I just use Microsoft's visual studio GUI to create branches and synch changes in...

Anyways here are a few print screens that might be useful:
[image: Image of missing repository and branch]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the working folder you selected contains a `.git` directory in it?

Comment: Is your code in TFVC (TFS version control) currently? If so, then you will need to manually move it to a new git repo. I would have thought that others in your company would have done this - speak to them to find out how they did it. If you are not familiar with git then you will need to learn it, there are plenty of online resources.

Comment: Yes contains .git folder. I updated from TFS quite a few years ago... I was the one that did the work. My other developers are not having an issue. Do you think I should just rebuild my repository and just merge in my changes after?

Comment: Just to clarify- "I have been coding for a solid 2 months within my master branch." You have been creating commits on your `master` branch using a different tool? (Not VS and not the command line?)

Comment: no I have not made any commits. I was trying to say that I kind of went coding and didn't do any check-ins... And then when I went to check in my code now the solution appears to be disconnected or broken.

Comment: Ah... so that means you haven't started using Git yet, and your repo may still be blank, which would explain why you can't see any branches. Note- until you create a commit, you haven't saved your work. For sanity purposes, the first thing you should do is make a complete backup of your code and put it outside of any Git repos. Now I think your question may be a little different, since it seems you need to make your first commit in a brand new repo. The basic steps are to a create (or find) a sensible `.gitignore` file, and then create the initial commit. I assume after that VS will see it.

Comment: No I am using VS built in git against DevOps! Anyways looks like somehow my .git folder got corrupted. Only solution I came up with was to clone to another folder and manually merge changes in using outside tools. I used CompareIT.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same thing.  Instead of using the Git window, i just selected the picklist at the bottom right corner where it is saying "Select Repository". The repository was in that picklist.  I selected it and everything was back to normal...sure freaked the hell outta me...

[used this picklist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4qhO.png)

Comment: it works for me as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just cloning my environment to another folder. Looks like that my .git folder somehow got corrupted. Then I manually moved my code using an application called CompareIT to merge in changes in files I suspected could be some conflicts with my other 2 developers. I was then able to push my changes and sync! Sorry I wish I had a better answer but that is about it!